# How to Show Reply container with same ID as Post container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building a social network-type website.

Each post has a set of replies. I have a ruby variable of (post.id) that I am using to distinguish between replies from one post, and replies from a different post.

The replies are initially hidden. How do I make it so that clicking the "open-replies" button, only shows replies for that post. Instead of opening all the replies, for every post.

Here is an example with the (post.id) variable being substituted with hard-coded numbers.

```
<a href="#" class="post-icon reply-open-13">Reply</a>
```

needs to open

```
<div class="reply-container reply-container-13 clearfix">
```

they both have the same "Post.id" and are both children of the

[http://codepen.io/sboland926/pen/ruwHz](http://codepen.io/sboland926/pen/ruwHz?editors=110)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass id as a separate attribute (ref in our case) so we can get via jquery later and call that id.

Modified HTML:

```
<div class="post-footer">
    <a href="#" class="post-icon">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="post-icon reply-open" ref="13">Reply</a>
</div>
<div id="reply-container-13" class="reply-container clearfix">
```

> Note: Just Replace 13 with your ruby post.id variable

JS:

```
$('.reply-open').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('ref');
    $('#reply-container-'+id).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

See it working here:
http://codepen.io/hasanhameed89/pen/hHlLr